# Python Counter class behaviour in for loop versus comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, counter, dictionary-comprehension

Could someone explain why the behaviour of the Counter class changes when using it in a loop versus in a comprehension? Below is a quick example:

```
>>> seqs = ["GATAGCTCGC", "GTAGAGCTCGCTC", "GTATATAGCTCGCCTG"]
>>> import collections
>>> counts1 = collections.Counter()
>>> for seq in seqs:
...     counts1.update(seq)
... 
>>> counts1
Counter({'G': 11, 'C': 11, 'T': 10, 'A': 7})
>>> counts2 = collections.Counter(seq for seq in seqs)
>>> counts2
Counter({'GTAGAGCTCGCTC': 1, 'GATAGCTCGC': 1, 'GTATATAGCTCGCCTG': 1})
```

Why does the update method split the input string into characters and count the characters instead of the entire string object? And how can I get the latter behaviour in a for loop?

Comment: In the first case, you are updating it with multiple sequences (of characters), in the latter case, you feed it just one sequence (of strings).

Comment: Do you think you're overcomplicating this?  `for seq in seqs: counts1[seq] += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update()` expect an iterable and will try to iterate on it, strings are iterables:

```
for seq in seqs:
    counts1.update(seq)
```

`seq` is `GATAGCTCGC` and will be used as `['G', 'A', 'T' ....]`

---

To have the same behavior, give it a list:

```
for seq in seqs:
    counts1.update([seq])
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings, lists, and other things are "[iterables](http://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/)" in Python, meaning they can be looped through.  In your `for` loop, you are passing each individual string to `counts1.update()`.  Since a string is an iterable, `counts1.update()` iterates through the string character-by-character, counting the individual characters.

In the list comprehension `seq for seq in seqs`, the list comprehension is itself an iterable providing three elements.  `collections.Counter()` iterates runs through the iterable it's given, which only has three elements, and counts each one.

Answer (score 0):

With `update` you pass a iterable that is traversed and the values are counted. Since `str` is considered iterable each character comes as a separate element and therefor counted.

In the constructor case the iterable consists of whole strings, so the strigns will be counted rather than the characters they consist of.